# How does C#/.NET implement pinning of ref/in/out parameters?

Tags: c#, .net

In "unsafe" C# code, it is possible to get a pointer to a `ref`, `in`, or `out` parameter by using the `fixed` statement:

```
class A
{
    unsafe void Test(ref int i)
    {
        fixed(int* ptr = &i)
        {
            // Do something with ptr.
        }
    }
}
```

The `fixed` statement "pins" the memory for `i` in place for the duration of the block so that the GC won't move the memory for `i` someplace else, which would invalidate `ptr`.

So my question, which I ask out of curiosity and a desire to better understand the performance implications of pinning `ref`/`in`/`out` parameters, is: **How does C# and/or the .NET runtime know what object, if any, actually needs to be pinned?** Because if `i` is a reference to a member field of an object, then doesn't it need to pin that whole object? And if `i` is a reference to a local variable in the calling function, then isn't there nothing that needs to be pinned at all? Does it somehow walk up the call stack until it finds the actual variable or field referred to by `i`? (Which sounds potentially expensive.)

Comment: Why do you think it's any different to pin a reference to a variable passed by reference or a reference to the variable itself?  In both cases you have a reference to the exact same variable, because there *is* only ever one variable in either situation.

Comment: This might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.alloc?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Comment: @Servy I don't understand what you mean by "a reference to a variable passed by reference" versus "a reference to the variable itself"?

Comment: @WaltD What don't you understand about it?  You showed an example of creating a reference to a variable passed by reference, and asked how it accomplishes what it would if you got a reference to the actual variable, rather than passing it as a by reference.

Comment: @dotnetstep Thanks for the links, but neither of them explain how pinning a ref/in/out parameter works.

Comment: @Servy No, I'm asking how the language/runtime knows what object (if any) to pin in memory when using the fixed statement with a ref/in/out parameter.

Comment: I definitely in the last month read an article which discussed the fact that the CLR has a method/mechanism by which it can take a reference that may be an *interior* reference within an object and determine the object that it's contained within. (Of course, it can also easily determine that it's not inside any managed heap areas). Can't locate the documentation at the moment. Might be covered in the "book of the runtime" documentation in Core CLR.

Comment: @WaltD And it's *identical* to how it does it without a parameter passed by reference, because there's literally no difference.  The fixed statement accepts an arbitrary pointer, and you have *exactly the same* arbitrary pointer in either case.

Comment: @Servy No, it's not at all identical. With an `int` (or any value type) that's passed by-value, you *cannot* use the `fixed` statement with it, you just do `&i` to get the pointer directly, which works since a by-value parameter is guaranteed to be located on the stack and thus won't be moved by the GC. With a value type passed by-`ref`, you *must* use the `fixed` statement to get a pointer to it, because the variable that was passed *might* actually be a member variable of a managed object that the GC could theoretically relocate, hence the necessity for pinning it.

Comment: It is gchandle. It has different option by that gc knows what to do with it

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I'll check that book out!

Comment: @WaltD But you're not comparing the code shown to passing a parameter by value, you're comparing it to fixing a field directly.  And it's identical to that.

Comment: The *fixed* statement does not generate any explicit pinning call, no gchandle either.  The GC discovers it when it consults the metadata that the jitter generates for a method while walking the stack, the ptr variable has the [pinned] attribute.  Treated like an interior pointer, there is a bit of slog associated with them.  The pointer value helps to quickly locate the heap segment but it has to walk the segment to find the object back.  Excessively hard to profile, you are just not unlucky often enough.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, I think that helps a lot. I was under the assumption that pinning set some flag in the object to prevent it from being moved. I guess it's more like, "if an object's memory contains a pinned address, don't move it". Thanks!